# How to document only attributes displayed on a class diagram?

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a class diagram showing tables and the relations. The tables have been restricted on the diagram to show only the attributes I'm interested in, using the "custom" button in the Feature Compartment Visibility dialog. I now want to use the document generator to document the classes and attributes displayed on the diagram in the document text.

[image: Suppress Displayed Attributes Dialog]

While I can use a virtual document with the appropriate query to select the classes in the diagram, passing that into a template which shows the attributes shows all of them. I can't find a way of reducing the list of attributes.

I could use a template to show the class header, and a custom fragment to query the attributes, but it would not be possible to determine within the custom script/sql which diagram was the relevant one, so that doesn't work.

Has anyone managed to do this without a third party tool?

Comment: did you try putting an element filter for attributes on the template? http://www.sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/model_publishing/rtf_element_filters.html

Comment: Actually ignore my last comment, element filters only document elements on which the filter applies, it doesn't apply on attributes

Comment: How do you define the attribute being visible on the diagram or not?

Comment: I've updated the question to clarify how the attributes are hidden in the diagram.

Comment: I figured this is what you did. I dont think you can access that which makes the attribute not visible on the diagram throught that functionality by sql, so you will need to assign metadata on the attribute so you can then get it by SQL (either by tagged value, or by stereotype as I described below, or with the scope) The metadata can be arbitrary and you will have to set the visibility indepedent, or the visibility can be set up according to the metadata, which I explain in my answer

Answer (score 2):

You can get that info in the field StyleEx of the t_diagram
The following example query returns the attributes that are shown on a particular diagram

```
select a.ea_guid,d.StyleEx from t_diagramobjects do
inner join t_object o on do.Object_ID = o.Object_ID
inner join t_diagram d on d.Diagram_ID = do.Diagram_ID
inner join t_attribute a on o.Object_ID = a.Object_ID
where o.ea_guid = '{0285FC6A-A2CE-479e-B374-5135BD74DACF}'
and d.StyleEx like '%SPL=S_%' + substring(a.ea_guid,2,6) + '%'
```

This works for SQL-Server, but needs to be adapted to suit your DBMS as substring and wildcards are database specific.

Comment: wouldn't that return all attributes that are not hidden on all diagrams for an object? So if all attributes are shown on another diagram, it will show the ones hidden in another diagram?

Comment: Thanks Geert - that works to remove the suppressed attributes if I know what the diagram guid or ID is. However, if I have a custom fragment for the attributes, then I need to know both the object I am diagramming, and the relevant diagram. I can't see how I can get both pieces of information within a custom script or query. The system will only give me the object_id.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a Scope on the attribute so they will be shown dependent of the scope, for example, your diagram can show only all public attributes.
You can then go into the Diagram Properties, on the features tab, and select which scopes you want to show

[image: 1]]

Or

You can set a stereotype, for example NotVisible, on an attribute you want to hide.

You then need to go in the feature visibility of each element, and enter the stereotypes you want to hide in the box in the bottom

[image]

There are other ways, but this is the gist of it

After that you can use fragments and query on attributes with the defined scope or stereotype

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem with this approach, is that I have one table, that will have say 5 columns needed on one diagram, and 3 on another, and so I'd have to add a stereotype that related to every diagram, and then a separate custom-fragment to exclude each diagram's specific stereotype. I think that would get messy very quickly.